# Display GPO deployed application's name on Windows 7 logon screen

Tags: windows-7, screen, authentication, gpo

On Windows XP, when an application is installed via GPO, user can see appplication's name during logon screen.

On Windows 7, the only status message is "Welcome".

Is there a way to display a more verbose welcome message on logon screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. See http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/04/best-practice-how-to-deploy-software-using-group-policy and scroll to **Tip #5**.

Comment: I'd been wondering about an easy way to do this.  Some of the GPO deployments take a while and once they sit at the "Please wait" screen for about 5 minutes some of them hard power cycle their desktops. Hopefully this will let them know that something is indeed happening while they wait.

Comment: By default, Windows 7 *should* display this information instead of "Please wait". Otherwise, user may thinks the computer is hanging and finally do an hard reboot.

Answer (score 0):

GPO -> Computer configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System ->

Win8, Win10: `Display highly detailed status messages`

Win7: `Verbose Status Messages`